# How to configure latest JSHint with Intellj Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, jshint

I am currently using JShint as a static analysis tool for my angular project. 
Though I am able to activate JSHint in Intellj idea via Settings -> java script -> JSHint enable. I am not able to find the latest version bundled  with my Idea installation in the version drop down.One more challenge is there are restrictions on internet access from the system. So my question is Is there an way to to configure the latest JShint standalone version with Idea?

Intellj Idea version: 12. 
JShint version to be configured: 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Goto Settings > Languages & frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality tools > JSHint
2. It will who below image
3. In there select the `Enable` checkbox
4. Select the version from `Version` dropdown
5. And finally click on `Apply` and then on `Ok` buttons

[image]

Comment: thanks for the replying leo but I already tried that. The issue is I am not able to find the JS hint version I am interested in ( 2.8.0) in the version drop down. I was searching for a way to have the latest version of JS Hint configured with Intell j idea. I also have a challenge of restrictions on internet access from the system I am working on so was searching for a way to configure standalone JShint package with Idea.